# Doctrine Migrations not recognizing the last migration

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

I'm using Doctrine Migrations and all migrations worked nice until now.
The last one I've created is not recognized on the staging server, but it works perfect on my local machine.

[image]

The bundle recognizes as the latest migration the version 20151006091137, but it should be 20151011132851.
As you can see in the image the migration file exists on the server.

On my local machine Doctrine sees correctly the latest version.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: It seems that nano was seeing the file, but when doing ls I couldn't see the file. Very strange. When I cd into app/DoctrineMigrations the file was there and the bundle started to see the file. Perhaps it was some unreadable state until I manually entered the folder.

Comment: Is your problem solved then ?

Comment: Yes. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

check into the table

```
doctrine_migrations
```

if your versionMigrations entry exist.
clear the cache

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

check if your entities is sync to database

```
app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

add new migration and you shouldn't have any addSql()

```
app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
```

Sync your migrations to database

```
app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate -y
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. In my case, it was environment issue. In other words, I was trying to run migration without using `--env`:

> bin/console doctrine:migrations:status // No migrations

But when I run with `--env=prod`

> bin/console doctrine:migrations:status --env=prod // Found migration

So i think it's related to caching issue or `PHP` configuration issue